# SharePoint calculated column to check if the cells of the row have value, if any of the cells have value then take up that value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I need a calculated column formula for following condition:

There are three columns "Column1", "Column2" & "Column3" in sharepoint list.
I want to check if any of these column have value in it. If yes then take that value in new calculated column: "Column4"

Comment: Please Note: I want this formula for Sharepoint List.

Also at a time only one column will have value in it.
that is among "Column1", "Column2" & "Column3", only one column will be having value.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use nested IF statements:

=IF(Column1="",IF(Column2="",IF(Column3="","",Column3),Column2),Column1)